# How to check if an array includes either X or Y

Tags: ruby

My assignment is to check whether a given input by the user contains the letters `"c"` or `"s"`. I managed with one but, I simply don't know the correct way to write that.

I know that the problem is `"s" || "c"`.

```
print 'What can we do for you?'
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!

if user_input.empty?
  puts 'Well you will have to write something...!'
elsif user_input.include? 's' || 'c'
  puts "We got ourselves some 's's and some 'c's"
  user_input.gsub!(/s/, 'th')
  user_input.tr!('c', 's')
  puts "The Daffy version, #{user_input}!"
else
  print "Nope, no 's' or 'c' found"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

simply

```
elsif user_input.include?("s") || user_input.include?("c")
```

or something like

```
%w(s c).any? { |command| user_input.include? command }
```

Comment: perfect man :) thanks a lot! Its so simply but this kept me glued to the screen for about an hour now. I just started ruby yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect example of where regular expressions are fine:

```
user_input =~ /[sc]/
```

Answer (score 1):

or:

```
(user_input.split('') & %w(s c)).any?
```

Comment: `user_input` is a string, for this to work one should `split` it: `(user_input.split('') & %w(s c)).any?`, but this approach is quite not effective.

Comment: @CarySwoveland
I thought that I deleted it
Thank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regexp

```
user_input[/s|c/]
```

Answer (score 0):

No regexp:

```
user_input.count('sc') > 0
```